# k-means in pandas dataframe, optimal k (number of clusters)?

Tags: dataframe, clustering

[image: df]

I have a dataframe like this. 
At first, i would like to calculate the optimal number of clusters and then I would like to use k-means without the last column (id). 
After that i would like to know the cluster of every row (id).
I did this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
features = list(df.columns)[:-2]
data = df[features]
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)

y = kmeans.fit_predict(data)

df['Cluster'] = y
```

[image: cl]

i believe it is right but i don't know how to know the optimal number of k before all these. How can i find it? Also, is what I did right? Because i then dropped the id column and I run:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)

y = kmeans.fit_predict(df)

df['Cluster'] = y
df[['Cluster']]
```

and the results were a liitle different.
But my main question is, how to find optimal number of clusters

Comment: this question has been answered many times, see for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23472/how-to-decide-on-the-correct-number-of-clusters) and the links in the answer